# Triage review for off-topic questions and Unsalvageable action

Tags: discussion, triage, flag-ban

I start reviewing Triage questions, taking into account Stack Overflow's policy on [off-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions.

Being careful to apply SO policy during my review, there are a lot of off-topic  questions that asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource which is considered  off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Even some questions asking to do his school homework and coding for him.

If I click skip for these questions (the easiest action) it will be, at least for me, a passive review.

These question can not be considered spam or duplicated and given my reputation, the only suitable action is clicking "Unsalvageable" and provide a comment like off-topic with explanation to be handled by moderator.

Some of the questions reach a score of -17 and should be closed ASAP to save time of the visitors to these questions, so clicking  Unsalvageable and provide a comment to be handled by a moderator was best choice (for me).

As a new Triage reviewer, I thought that using flags was necessary, as it's used  carefully and fit for the purpose.

I find myself disabled from Triage review with a title "Too many of your recent flags have been declined."

**My questions:**

- What is the best action for off-topic questions in Triage review?
- What can I do about the declined flags?

Comment: Have you ever clicked "Unalvageable"?

Comment: @Braiam `so clicking Unsalvageable and provide a comment to be handled by moderator was best choice (for me).` sounds like it.

Comment: @Servy this sounds like an usability bug then...

Comment: @Braiam it's not usability bug. I thought that "should be closed" is for 3k permutations, but now from Servey answer i can use this option.

Comment: I learn a little bit every day! . If i review the flagging history  in my profile, I wasn't panned. I hope SO provide an early warning message before panning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're flagging these posts for moderator attention.  Don't do that.  When a post merits closure, you should be flagging the post for closure, which won't end up being reviewed by a moderator at all.

> [image: proper flag option in dialog]

If you flag a post for moderator attention *when a different type of flag should have been used*, the moderator is going to decline the flag.  You can check whether this is the case in your flagging history in your profile.

Sometime within the next few weeks your flag ban will end, and you'll be able to access the review queue again as long as you're able to flag post appropriately going forward.

Oh, and while we're at it, if you know a post is problematic *you generally shouldn't be skipping it*.  You should skip a post if you don't know if it's acceptable or unacceptable.  If you're confident that a post is problematic, you should be indicating as much in the queue (in this case, by marking it as unsalvageable for the appropriate reason).

Comment: I misunderstand that  "should be closed" is for  3k permutation :). Now i understand the right action. Thanks for help.